# Convert time to DateTime using moment js

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I have time in `HH:mm` format like `13:15`.  I want to convert it into `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm` using moment.js .

I tried the following code.

```
var t = "13:56"; 
var cdt = moment(t).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
alert(cdt);
```

I wanted output with the current date and given time like `2015-21-05 13:56`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use [string-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) moment constructor to pass string and format in which input string is.

*Use*

```js
var t = "13:56"; 
var cdt = moment(t, 'HH:mm');
console.log(cdt.toDate());
console.log(cdt.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Deprecation warning: This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release.

Comment: @NeoPix What was it replaced by...?